# How to rollover image with time delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually in the products page, we want to reduce the burden on the server to bring the images only after delay of 2 to 3 seconds on mouse over. So If the user hover the cursor we should hit the server after 2 seconds and bring the new image. But the below code is not working as per our expectation.

**HTML Tag:**

```
<img class="rollover-images" data-rollover="{bringNewImage()}" src="{bringOldImage()}" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.rollover-images').each(function() {

        var newSrc = $(this).data('rollover');
        if(newSrc == 0) return;

        var timeout, oldSrc;
        $(this).hover(function() {

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {

                oldSrc = $(this).attr('src');
                $(this).attr('src', newSrc).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn(1);

            }, 2000);

        }, function() {

            clearTimeout(timeout);
            $(this).attr('src', oldSrc).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn(1);

        });

    });
```

Comment: What *is* happening?

Comment: Any problem with the question asked? Why it is -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the posted code

You cannot put in a javascript function for an HTML attribute and expect it to be replaced by the function return value. So your HTML should be

```
<img class="rollover-images" data-rollover="new.png" src="old.png" />
```

You have a problem with this inside the timeout function. Since you have begun a new function scope, the value of this won't be your img node. So your JS should be

```
$(this).hover(function () {
    var self = this
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        oldSrc = $(self).attr('src');
        $(self).attr('src', newSrc).stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(1);
    }, 2000);
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).attr('src', oldSrc).stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(1);
});
```

Notice that we defined a new variable called self which is used  inside the setTimeout call.

Comment: Thanks a Lot!. Its working. The HTML sample given only for reference. We are handling the code as part of our framework.